# SSD and HDD Internal Raid system compatible with external clone docking station

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, docking-stations, raid

I'm searching for a good internal raid system for two SSDs and one for two HDDs. The housing of the SSDs and HDDs should be compatible with an external docking station, which I want to use for Backups. So I must also be able to buy extra housings for backup disks.

Do you know a good solution, for this kind of setup?

I prefer easy use and quality over the cheapest solution, but if there is a cheap solution fulfilling my needs, I would choose this one.